# How to execute stored procedure using Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi

Tags: sitecore-api, sql-database

I am trying to execute SQL stored procedure from C# code using `Sitecore data providers`. I am using the `SqlDataApi` class from `Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql` but not finding any method which accepts a stored procedure name as an input parameter.

Kindly help on this if somebody did it in any Sitecore project.

Comment: For what reason do you need to use that API? Why not just use the standard .Net APIs?

Comment: Actually I am accessing form database using SqlDataApi. To use .Net APIs I need to open a new connection of form data base which I don't want. Because I already open a connection to access data base using SqlDataApi.